# A problem from python crash course by google

Tags: python, list

The group_list function accepts a group name and a list of members, and returns a string with the format: group_name: member1, member2, … For example, group_list("g", ["a","b","c"]) returns "g: a, b, c". Fill in the gaps in this function to do that.

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ___
  return ___

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

**I have tried sth like this:**

```
members = " " 
for i in users:
    members += ",".join(i)
return ("{}:{}".format(group, members))
```

output comes:

```
Marketing: M,i,k,eK,a,r,e,nJ,a,k,eT,a,s,h,a
Engineering: K,i,mJ,a,yT,o,m
Users:
```

**but it didn't give the expected answer. Can anyone solve it with filling the blanks please ?**

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need help with? What's confusing you?

Comment: look into the `",".join` function. I am sure the crash course mentions the `str.join` method.

Comment: I am not getting the expected answers

Comment: Does .join function matter? I mean it gives the same output

Comment: `return "group:members"` - This will *always* give the literal string `"group:members"`.  Looks like you want format strings: `return f"{group}: {members}"`.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code? It's not a runnable example right now. And I have no idea what `for name[:len(user)] in users` is supposed to do, that's vaguely python-shaped gibberish. What is `name`? What is `user`?

Comment: I have given the original problem now

Comment: We *do* want to see your code, taking it out will get the question closed just as fast as having confusing stuff in there. Try to make a [mcve] showing what you're trying to do and what the result is, as well as what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: Sir, I have added what I did the last time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join `users`, not each user separately.

```
members = ', '.join(users)
return "{}: {}".format(group, members)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members =", ".join(users) 
  return(" {}: {}".format(group, members)) 

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return group + ": " + (", ".join(users))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out a more shorter way to achieve same result using the format 'f' method.

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ", ".join(users)
  return f"{group}: {members}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try this one`

```
def group_list(group, users):
    members = " " 
    for i in users:`
        members+=",".join(users)
        break
    return "{}:{}".format(group,members)**
print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
def group_list(group, users):
    members = ", ".join(users)
    return "{}: {}".format(group,members)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give desired results:

```
 def group_list(group, users):
 members = ""
 for user in users:
   members += user + ", "
 return "{}: ".format(group) + members
```